# ¿Como recibir un objeto desde un formulario en Struts2?

Tags: struts, struts2

Como puedo recibir en un action un objeto desde un formulario, para asi evitar los getter y setter para recibir campo a campo?

Ejemplo en Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registro", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String crearUsuario(@ModelAttribute Usuario user,HttpServletRequest req) {
        ModelMap  model = new ModelMap();
        registrarUsuario.crearUsuario(user);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("idUsuario",user.getIdUsuario());
        req.getSession().setAttribute("usuario",user.getNomUsuario());

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

En este caso estoy recibiendo un objeto usuario,  como seria su equivalente en un action de en struts2?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu struts `Action` crea sólo un getter y setter para tu objecto, por ejemplo Usario:

```
Usuario getUsuario(){
  return this.usario;
}

void setUsuario(Usuario usuario){
 this.usuario = usuario;
}
```

En el jsp, dentro de tu forma, puedes usar tags de struts2 para accesar los atributos del Usuario:

```
<s:form ...>
    <s:textfield name="usuario.nombre" label=...>
    <s:textfiled name="usuario.apellido" label=...>
<s:form/>
```

Y la clase Usuario es la que tiene los getters y setters para cada atributo:

```
public class Usuario {
  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;

  String getNombre(){return nombre;}
  String getApellido(){return apellido;}
  void setNombre(String nombre){this.nombre = nombre;}
  void setApellido(String apellido){this.apellido = apellido;}
}
```